# Find a document with ObjectID in mongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

When I inserted some documents into a collection (without an ObjectID) mongoDB adds its own ObjectIDs.

I want to query a document by its unique ObjectID.

```
$db->collection_name->find(array('_id'=>'4e49fd8269fd873c0a000000')));
```

It does not work either with prefix of MongoID or ObjectID in front of '4e49fd8269fd873c0a000000'.

What is the proper way to query by ObjectID with mongoDB in PHP?

Comment: It works in console with "ObjectID" in front of 4e49fd... but not in PHP.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Pretty sure you have to use a [`MongoId`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongoid.php) object, eg

```
$item = $collection->findOne(array(
    '_id' => new MongoId('4e49fd8269fd873c0a000000')));
```

The notes on the [Querying](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.queries.php) page are a little obtuse but it does mention...

> Unless the user has specified otherwise, the _id field is a MongoId. The most common mistake is attepting to use a string to match a MongoId. Keep in mind that these are two different datatypes, and will not match each other in the same way that the string "array()" is not the same as an empty array

Comment: I write same query, but query is not working. $collection = $db->Collection("video_detail");
  
    $cursor = $collection->findOne(array('user_id' => new MongoId("575289f33a31b98a4c8b4567")));

Answer (score 29):

I think now the API changes to `MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID`, also you can use `[]` to denote an array in PHP 5.4+, so it should be:

```
$item = $collection->findOne(['_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID( idToken )]);
```

based on Phil's answer.

Comment: This works for me, but I am at a bit of a loss to understand where `MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID` comes from. It's not defined anywhere in the `vendor/mongodb` folder as a separate class, as far as I can see. NetBeans is normally good at project introspection, but it can't see it either. And yet it works!

Comment: Thanks you so much man. Really Appreciate.  Your are Start for me.

Comment: For me new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID( idToken )] worked for me, notice the "\". Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

For MongoDB\Driver\Manager, a modern version of a MongoDB, you might consider the following working code:

```
try {
  $DB_CONNECTION_STRING="mongodb://YourCredentials";
  require '../../vendor/autoload.php';
  $manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager( $DB_CONNECTION_STRING );

  $filter = ['_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID( '5bdf54e6d722dc000f0aa6c2' )];
  $options = [];

  $query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);     
  $docs = $manager->executeQuery('YourDbName.YourCollectionName', $query);
}
catch (MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception $e) { 
  $filename = basename(__FILE__); 
  echo "The $filename script has experienced an error.\n"; 
  echo "It failed with the following exception:\n"; 
  echo "Exception:", $e->getMessage(), "\n"; 
}
```

For testing purposes:

```
foreach ($docs as $doc) {
  print_r($doc);
  //or you can: echo "$doc->item  $row->qty  $row->status<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With [alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter](https://packagist.org/packages/alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter) (under php 7), needed to convert `\MongoId` to BSON type:

```
$filter = [];
$filter['_id'] = (new \MongoId('4e49fd8269fd873c0a000000'))->toBSONType();
$cursor = $collection->find($filter);
```

Comment: with php 8 how to use a custom oid instead of the default mongodb one ? like "ABCD"   
php -version
PHP 8.0.11 (cli) (built: Sep 23 2021 22:04:56) ( NTS )  
Copyright (c) The PHP Group  
Zend Engine v4.0.11, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies  
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.11, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies  
# php --ri mongodb | grep version  
MongoDB extension version => 1.10.0  
libbson bundled version => 1.18.0  
libmongoc bundled version => 1.18.0  
libmongocrypt bundled version => 1.2.1

Comment: ERROR:MongoDB\Driver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Error parsing ObjectId string: 0F000001