# Why php mongo $in search won't work for ObjectId?

Tags: php, mongodb, search

I'm new here.
I'm trying to search multiple ObjectIds in MongoDB using '$in' under PHP.
And it runs OK on RockMongo.
but it seems no luck in my own PHP codes.

Here is what I did.

In RockMongo

```
{
_id: {'$in': [ ObjectId("54c8a7446abe4688010041ae"), ObjectId("54c8a7446abe4688010041ad") ]}
}
```

In PHP

```
$tagsDB = self::getTagsDB();
$res = $tagsDB->find(array(
    '_id' => array('$in' => $tagIds)
  ));
```

`$tagsDB` is MongoClient connection and `$res` gives me `MongoCursor::__set_state(array( ))`

`$tagIds` is an array of `ObjectId`.

If you could help me out, that would be great!
Please let me know if I need to provide further information.

best,

Comment: Are you using `new MongoId()` in `$tagIds` - as per the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074309/find-a-document-with-objectid-in-mongodb

Comment: @DaveCoast Thx for reply. Fortunately, yes I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spending some time of research, try and error, and finally found the solution.

`$res` is MongoCursor object and I need to use [`iterator_to_array()`](http://php.net/manual/ro/class.mongocursor.php#106273) to show result values.

```
var_export(iterator_to_array($res));
```